# How to combine two variable inside another variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a variable:

```
$a="t123";
```

I have another variable named:

```
$t123;
```

I can not call the varibale `$t123` directly as the numaric  value is changable.

I Want like this:

```
$new = $.$a; //NOT working.
```

Any solution? Thanks.

Comment: [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php): `$new = $$a;`

Comment: Just do `$var = ${$a};`

Comment: This sounds as though `$t123` would be better suited as an array.

Comment: It's a lot better to organize your data into regular structures like an array than to use variable names as pointers. `$t = array('123' => '...')` is *way* better than `$t123 = '...'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A so-called 'variable variable' should do the trick:

```
$new = $$a;
```

This basically substitutes the value of `$a` as the variable name to use for the assignment.

More information can be found in the docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Personally I don't like variable variables at all and tend to avoid them, because it feels as weird magic to me. 
I rather use a more 'official' key/value pair solution like arrays or objects that can be used as a dictionary. But then again, I work in multiple languages, and PHP just on the side, so what may seem weird to me may be very common to full-time PHP developers.

Comment: I am a full-time PHP developer and I also think variable variables are weird.

Comment: @Don'tPanic They're not just weird, they're probably a super bad idea. You can get yourself into a whole world if hurt if you let users assign the value you're de-referencing. This is one of those super quirky things that PHP inherited from Perl.

Comment: @tadman I've never really understood why they even exist, even in Perl. It seems like people would want to just write their code in a way that would let them know what all their variables are called instead.

Comment: @Don'tPanic In the context of Perl it fits in a lot better, but only because Perl is notoriously ridiculous in terms of syntax. If you're making a small shell script where you have a lot of control over the environment it's running in it can be useful, it's a shortcut that shell scripting tools lacked. If you're writing a web application it's dangerously close to `eval` in terms of implications.

Answer (score 2):

This is called Variable Variables. There are a few ways you can do this, I.E:

**Method 1:**

```
$new = ${$a};
```

**Method 2:**

```
$new = $$a;
```

I tend to use method 1 more often than method 2, as I find it easier to really understand what is going on and what that specific line is doing.

Either of these methods will make `$new` equal to the value of a variable named the value of `$a` is.

You can read more about variable variables [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).